# Can Mathematica Take Advantage Of a AMD Ryzen Threadripper 2990wx 32 Core Processor?

Tags: numerical-integration, performance-tuning, list-manipulation, parallelization

I have a student version of Mathematica. I'm currently running it on my 8 Core Desktop. On my current Desktop I use it for Numerically integrating expressions 1000s of times, the ParallelTable function comes in handy for that. If I upgrade to a 32 core processor, will Mathematica use all 32 cores for ParallelTable or will it only use a portion of that? Thanks

Comment: As others have indicated, the student version is limited to 4 kernels.  Given this, if your computation times are very long, you might want to look into what resources your school's computing center has.  Wolfram offers specialized licenses that allow >4 kernels to be run, and your school may have purchased one of these to run on one of its clusters.

Comment: I know that it is limited to 4 kernels but it does run 8 cores when I do paralleltable. Are you saying that with my licenses I can only run 8 cores max, or if I add more cores will it run those if I use paralleltable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> If I upgrade to a 32 core processor, will Mathematica use all 32 cores for ParallelTable or will it only use a portion of that?

It will only use as many parallel kernels as your license permits. For the student desktop versions you can look [it up here](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/pricing/students-individuals.php). As you can see, you won't have more than 4 computational kernels.

With my license, I have 8 computational kernels and when I use the preferences to force it to start 10, I get an error message that clearly says that 2 of them could not be started

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The other type of parallelism that is provided through `Compile` with `Parallelization -> True` and other built-in functions of Mathematica does not have this restriction though.

Comment: Thanks a lot, so as long a I keep ParallelTable in the same Kernel, it will use 32 cores to divide the task?

Answer (score 3):

If you go to `Preferences->Parallel`, you should see a section that shows how many cores Mathematica can use. Off the top of my head, I don't think the Student Edition can use 32 cores, but more generally Mathematica will use as many cores as you provide it.

Comment: I'll look into it, thank you very much!

Comment: 32 cores on student edition, really? Quick look on WRI pages would indicate "4 computation kernels", the same as in Home Edition (which definitely limits core usage to 4) and even lower-end professional licenses are the same, I think. There's a chance that some numerical linear algebra functions use all cores, but that's a different story.